# Security level of DSA when $q$ is a 224 bit prime?

Tags: dsa

What is the security level of DSA algorithm when $q$ is a 224 bit prime?

Is it always a simple rule that the security level is the bit length of $q$ divided by two ?

Comment: 112, see [page 67](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r5.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for that link. I think you mean page 54.

Comment: Yes, I've given the pdf page, and you see the doc page, :)

Comment: Does 112 mean it takes $2^{112}$ operations to solve the discrete logarithm problem in the DSA algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the security level of DSA algorithm when q is a 224 bit prime?

About 112-bit, at most. More precisely, there's an attack recovering the private key from the public key, by solving a Discrete Logarithm Problem, costing roughly $2^{113}$ modular multiplications, and little else: the attack can be efficiently distributed and requires little memory. See Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Wiener, [*Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications*](https://people.scs.carleton.ca/%7Epaulv/papers/JoC97.pdf), in [Journal of Cryptology, 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816).

> Is it always a simple rule that the security level is the bit length of $q$ divided by two ?

No. That rule applies unless there's another weakness:

- The public prime $p$ is too small (or of a special form facilitating attack). As a rule of thumb, size (and requirement to not be too close to an exact power) are comparable to that of $n$ in RSA for the desired security level, in order to resist [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm) and [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) variants. That would make about 2048-bit a minimum. See [KeyLength.com](https://www.keylength.com/) for more precise advice on size.
- The random generator used for signing has an exploitable weakness.
- The private key leaks, e.g. by power analysis or timing attack.

Comment: Thank you. Does $2^{113}$ operations refer to the number of operations needed to solve the discrete logarithm problem which cracks the DSA algorithm?

Comment: @Gabi23: Yes. I added that in the answer.

Comment: Could you please point to the place in the paper where this is mentioned? I don’t see where it mentions the number of operations.